# Android Button Doing Opposite of Command

Tags: android, android-button

So I just started using the Android Development kit and learned how to create buttons and get them to work. To test what I know I made a simple app that displays "correct" if you click the button on the right and "idiot" if you click the one on the left. Everything is working other than the fact that it's displaying the opposite message for the button clicked.

Here is my xml code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textv1"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="Click the Right Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textv1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/left"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textv1" />
```

Here is my Java code:

```
    package com.clicktherightbutton;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button rightb;
Button leftb;
TextView Display;

String yes = "Correct!!!";
String no = "Idiot!!!";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    rightb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.right);
    leftb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.left);
    Display=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textv1);

    rightb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(rightb.isPressed())
                Display.setText(yes);
                rightb.setEnabled(false);
                leftb.setEnabled(false);
        }
    });

    leftb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(leftb.isPressed())
                Display.setText(no);
                rightb.setEnabled(false);
                leftb.setEnabled(false);

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}
```

I understand if I switch "left" and "right" the buttons will do as I want but I want to know why it's doing the opposite of what I coded it to do? Is something wrong with my code?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

Change your layout to:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textv1"
    android:layout_width="149dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="57dp"
    android:text="Click the Right Button" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/left"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/textv1"
    android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/textv1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/right"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/left"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@id/left"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/textv1" />
```

You can only declare `@+id` once - it creates a variable. Later use `@id` to reference the same variable.

Comment: I tried what you said but I got the same result. Thanks for the tip though.

Comment: Are you sure the buttons are correctly laid out? Can you add a text to them to check which is which.

Comment: I just added text and left was left and right was right. It also shows the right Id when I click them on the GUI, which makes me even more confused on how they're getting mixed up.

Comment: I closed and reopened my project file and it started working... Wow. Thank you for trying to help me with this.